# OR statement in the arguments of method

Tags: ios, objective-c, arguments, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a method like this:

```
-(void)exampleSend:(NSString *)gateway byParams:(NSDictionary *)params{
    ...
}
```

Now I want to change `params` , which is an input argument, to something that support both `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`. How can I do this in objective-c ?

Comment: Use `id` or introduce an own data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type to `id` instead of `NSDictionary` and make sure you should check inside your method if its `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` before performing any class specific actions on it, otherwise it will cause a crash.

```
-(void)exampleSend:(NSString *)gateway byParams:(id)params{

    if([params isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

    }else{

    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is one possible solution. But I want to ensure in the argument passing, not inside the method. I see something like "id or null" in the some methods and hope to find such a thing to use in this situation too, if objective-c permits.

Comment: If I may ask, why is that? Even if you pass either a NSArray or NSDictionary you will still have to perform actions depending on the class using an `if` condition either way?

Comment: Objective-C does not support method overloading, so there's no way to accomplish what you're after, without introducing a new type that wraps an array or dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C doesn't support passing two different data types to the same parameter. Using `id` is one option (which you don't seem to like based on the comments of the other answer).

Another option is to have two methods. Something like the following:

```
-(void)exampleSend:(NSString *)gateway byParamsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)params{
    ...
}

-(void)exampleSend:(NSString *)gateway byParamsArray:(NSArray *)params{
    ...
}
```

It's like these two methods will have some common code. Put that common code into a third method and have of these two methods call the common method as needed. The code in these two methods should be specific to dealing with the two different parameter types.